# WebApi - Referential integrity check before delete event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to delete Tags from the database. There is a another collection of items called Pages. Each Page has multiple Tags. How can I ensure that a Tag does not belong to any Page before deletion occurs? Any suggestions?

Here's my progress so far. It's the default delete action with an addition of two variables:

```
    // DELETE api/Tag/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteTag(int id)
    {
        // Added variables
        var nullTags = db.Tags.Where(c => c.Pages.Count == 0);
        var matched = db.Tags.Where(c => c.TagId == id);

        Tag tag = db.Tags.Find(id);
        if (tag == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Tags.Remove(tag);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tag);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ensure the tag doesn't have any pages.

```
var tag = db.Tags.SingleOrDefault(t => t.id == id);

if (tag == null) 
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}

if (tag.Pages.Any()) 
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
        "A tag must not be assigned to any page before you delete it"
    );
}

db.Tags.Remove(tag);
db.SaveChanges();

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first row to:

```
Tag tag = db.Tags.Where(c => (c.id == id) && (c.Pages.Count == 0)).FirstOrDefault();

if (tag != null) {
    //It does not have pages, so you can delete it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not enable referential integrity on the DB level? if you are using MSSQL this is easy. I am wondering is there is a specific reason to this to be handled in the application level when it can be handled in the DB level much easily?